# Keep a bootstrap modal open, from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple modal, which comprises of the standard ASP.NET requried field validators, which takes care of the end user not suppling the neccessary fields, when they submit the form.

This all works, fine. However, I do some further validatio of the username field, which uses ASP.NET Identity to validate the username is valid. When the username is invalid, I use the same error validator as previously, however once ASP.NET has finished processing the method, the modal is automatically, closed, and the user doesnt see the message, until the fire up the modal again.

How can I keep the modal dialog from closing, until I am happy to do so?

Code below for both modal and code behind:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLostPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Password recovery</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body row-fluid">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-default">
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-white rounded">

            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p>Please complete the below fields, and click submit. We will email you a temporary password.</p>
          </div>
          <%-- <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
            <div id="completeTxtWarning" class="alert alert-danger">Please</div>
        </div>--%>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ResetPasswordErrorMessage" Visible="false">
          <p class="text-danger">
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ResetPasswordFailureText" />
          </p>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>

      </div>
      <div id="pnlLostPassword" class="container-fluid panel-danger">
        <div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="confirmUserName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username.." />
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="ResetPasswordValidationGroup" ControlToValidate="confirmUserName" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="confirmEmail" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Email.." />
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="confirmEmailValidator" ValidationGroup="ResetPasswordValidationGroup" ControlToValidate="confirmEmail" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

      <asp:Button ID="btnSendNewPassword" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Reset" OnClick="SendNewPassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ResetPasswordValidationGroup"></asp:Button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

C#

```
 protected void SendNewPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            var userName = confirmUserName.Text;
            var emailAddress = confirmEmail.Text;

            // Generate random password.
            string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);

            // create new manager
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            // find the userName supplied.
            var user = manager.FindByName(userName);
            if (user != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // cannot find a user for the 
                ResetPasswordFailureText.Text = "Unknown username";
                ResetPasswordErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ResetPasswordFailureText.Text = "Invalid username, or email address.";
            ResetPasswordErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify on how this is communicating with the server?  Are you sending AJAX requests to the server to check the username or are you submitting the form and reloading the entire page?  If the former, can you post your javascript?

Comment: Hi Michael, this is all being posted by the standard asp.net post mechanism, and this I believe is why it closes. I just need a way to keep it open. I can use ajax, calling into a WebMethod, but then i'd have to create my own validators

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try a couple of things:

- reopen the modal after the postback via javascript if you need to show a message. For example you can store a value in an hidden field and then check with javascript. I think this is a simple solution.
- you can use update panels to update the page and not the modal. You should eventually close the dialog if the validation is OK. This is a little bit harder than just reopen the modal.
- as last option you can rebuild server side the modal markup with the correct classes.  I would not do it but if don't find anything better...

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for your response - but reopening, the modal, is great UX - I may be forced to roll my own validators, and use simple Ajax/WebMethods.

Comment: I like the reopen modal idea if that works for you because all you have to do is have a hidden checkbox for example that you set when the form gets sent so on postback you check it with JS and if it is set you just open the modal `$('#modal').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

Just use ASP.NET's ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to do a $('#modalLostPassword').modal('show'); when the validation fails

Comment: again, this will assumably, close and then reopen right?

Comment: actually the close doesn't actually happen, when you do a full postback, you are basically getting a new HTML page where the dialog is in its initial state (i.e. closed). Now, you open it.